# Sort objects by time

Tags: javascript, sorting

I want to sort these array of objects from earliest to latest in regards to time. (The opposite to what it is now i.e. old messages should appear on top of array). I know we can use `Date.parse` to turn the dates into milliseconds and then we can use `function sortBy(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}` function to sort them.

But I am having trouble putting it all together.

Here is the data:

```
const messagesArray = [
  {id: "92196bd0-b326-4b04-9520-1e8e4814f5e4", message: "ghghhghg", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:15.473Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}, 
  {id: "c5a35080-8f5b-49f7-8216-d6b94e543c44", message: "gghhghgh", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:13.103Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "2046cdda-47cd-492f-8534-a58fe5f5091f", message: "dffffffffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:45.598Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "649534f7-34d6-45ae-98b2-ac1189cf9337", message: "ddfffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:44.105Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}
];
```

Comment: Since you already have them sorted in the opposite way you want, if you read the array from the end, that would be fine too I think!

Answer (score 1):

In order to sort the objects by time you first need to convert the strings to time objects (that can be comparable):

```js
const messagesArray = [
  {id: "92196bd0-b326-4b04-9520-1e8e4814f5e4", message: "ghghhghg", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:15.473Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}, 
  {id: "c5a35080-8f5b-49f7-8216-d6b94e543c44", message: "gghhghgh", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:13.103Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "2046cdda-47cd-492f-8534-a58fe5f5091f", message: "dffffffffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:45.598Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "649534f7-34d6-45ae-98b2-ac1189cf9337", message: "ddfffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:44.105Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}
];

messagesArray.sort((a, b) => {return new Date(a.message_time) - new Date(b.message_time)});
console.log(messagesArray);
```

Comment: No need to convert to dates - ISO8601 is sortable lexicographically. It's part of the standard.

Comment: Awesome! Nicely explained.

Comment: @VLAZ assuming the data is indeed ISO8601 - you are correct :-)

Comment: @Dekel assuming it's *not* ISO8601, then it can't be safely converted via feeding it into `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
const messagesArray = [
  {id: "92196bd0-b326-4b04-9520-1e8e4814f5e4", message: "ghghhghg", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:15.473Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}, 
  {id: "c5a35080-8f5b-49f7-8216-d6b94e543c44", message: "gghhghgh", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:13.103Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "2046cdda-47cd-492f-8534-a58fe5f5091f", message: "dffffffffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:45.598Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "649534f7-34d6-45ae-98b2-ac1189cf9337", message: "ddfffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:44.105Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}
];
var sortedByDate = messagesArray.sort(function(a,b) { 
  return new Date(a.message_time).getTime() - new Date(b.message_time).getTime() 
});
console.log(sortedByDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as your dates are

- in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format
- all the same timezone

You can use normal lexicographical (string) sorting here. It's safe, since ISO 8601 formatted dates *always* go from most significant to least, so sorting them in alphabetic order will *always* produce ascending dates. Or reverse alphabetic for descending dates:

```js
const messagesArray = [
  {id: "92196bd0-b326-4b04-9520-1e8e4814f5e4", message: "ghghhghg", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:15.473Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}, 
  {id: "c5a35080-8f5b-49f7-8216-d6b94e543c44", message: "gghhghgh", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:13.103Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "2046cdda-47cd-492f-8534-a58fe5f5091f", message: "dffffffffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:45.598Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "649534f7-34d6-45ae-98b2-ac1189cf9337", message: "ddfffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:44.105Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}
];

messagesArray.sort((a, b) => a.message_time.localeCompare(b.message_time));

console.log(messagesArray)
```

If you are already getting them sorted opposite to what you want, you can simply use [`Array#reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```js
const messagesArray = [
  {id: "92196bd0-b326-4b04-9520-1e8e4814f5e4", message: "ghghhghg", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:15.473Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}, 
  {id: "c5a35080-8f5b-49f7-8216-d6b94e543c44", message: "gghhghgh", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:50:13.103Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "2046cdda-47cd-492f-8534-a58fe5f5091f", message: "dffffffffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:45.598Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null},
  {id: "649534f7-34d6-45ae-98b2-ac1189cf9337", message: "ddfffffffff", message_time: "2020-03-11T12:47:44.105Z", interaction_id: "08350527-770e-42eb-ad3c-33a73250bc20", post_user_ref: null}
];

messagesArray.reverse();

console.log(messagesArray)
```

Answer (score -2):

Since you already have them sorted in the opposite way you want, if you read the array from the end, that would be fine too I think!

Comment: I have added a comment too.